# SSZipArchive does not open document Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ssziparchive

I can't understand what happened. In my project when I try to convert file from zip to some files it does not work. When I did research I found that "unzOpenInternal" does not open file. 
I used this library in other projects. All worked well. But now I don't know what happened.
I added libz.tbd library and path to file is correct. If I try to load this file in NSData it is loading.

```
        NSString *path1 = [dataPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
        path1 = [path1 stringByAppendingString:@"/Pictures"];
        if ([SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:dataPath toDestination:path1]) {

        }
```

What can it be ?

File path for dataPath

> (lldb) p dataPath
>   (NSPathStore2 *) $1 = 0x7c8dd9f0 @"/Users/ZHENIA/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/54BDC20B-59C5-4DFF-BD0B-5CB0EFD133DB/data/Containers/Data/Application/610B5E19-2569-499E-9B95-25C3E1BAC72C/Library/Caches/test.zip"

File path for path1:

> (lldb) p path1
>   (__NSCFString *) $0 = 0x7ce26870 @"/Users/ZHENIA/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/54BDC20B-59C5-4DFF-BD0B-5CB0EFD133DB/data/Containers/Data/Application/610B5E19-2569-499E-9B95-25C3E1BAC72C/Library/Caches/Pictures"

Comment: It would be helpful if you would evaluate each of these variables in the debugger and (path1, dataPath) and post their values.  Otherwise, it is just trying to speculate on why code that usually works isn't in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I added values from debugger

Comment: Are you sure the `test.zip` is a valid file ? If this file was downloaded, there is a possibility that the file may get corrupt.

Comment: @NeverHopeless, Yes. I found it into the library and open with the help of zip archiver. It works well with the help of test project too.

Comment: @NeverHopeless, Sorry, this file was corrupted. Thank you very-very much. What can be reason of corrupted file? If I load it from browser it downloads without mistakes

Comment: There is a problem in downloading and saving file mechanism. make sure you downloaded till the last byte. for that you can use some reliable library rather than your own code. once the file gets extracted in finder the code will hopefully start working.